# is it possible to get aws sns reply email notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I need to capture users email reply.
EXP: after receiving an email,if user is replying to that email, I need to capture user replied or not using AWS SNS can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not capture use email reply directly with SNS, you can not publish to SNS from email, but one way to do that is to have email listening server, receive email and publish email back to SNS.

You can use [mailin](https://github.com/Flolagale/mailin), process the receiving email, it also support webhook, At this point, Mailin will listen for incoming emails, parse them and post an urlencoded form multipart/form-data to your **webhook url**.

> Mailin is an smtp server that listens for emails, parses them and
>   posts them as json to the url of your choice. It checks the incoming
>   emails dkim, spf, spam score (using spamassassin) and tells you in
>   which language the email is written.

High-level look can be

[image]